# Richfaces tooltip not working for h:outputlink tag?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, tooltip, download, commandlink

I am using JSF 2.0 & Richfaces 4.0 for my project.There is one model as download file and for that purpose I used 
h:outputlink to download file.The file downloads properly.But i used icon to show download option & attached rich:tooltip to show tooltip when mouse hover on that icon but it is not showing.If I used a4j:commandlink then tooltip shows but i cant implelement download functionality using a4j:commandlink. Can anybody tell me what is the reason that  tooltip is not working for h:outputlink?   Here is my code...

```
<h:outputLink rendered="#{docList.docType=='FILE' and not empty docList.docName}" value="/FileDownload" title="Download Documents">
                            <f:param name="fileId" value="#{docList.docId}"/>
                            <f:param name="fileName" value="#{docList.docName}"/>
                            <f:param name="fileSize" value="#{docList.docLength}"/>
                        <h:graphicImage library="images" name="doc_save_icon.png" style="border:0;"/>
                        <rich:tooltip styleClass="tooltip" layout="block" mode="ajax" value="Download Documents">
                                 Download Documents
                        </rich:tooltip>
                    </h:outputLink>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh you missed sth the for attribute and id example

```
<h:commandLink value="TEST12" action="STH" **id="cmdlnk"** />
<rich:toolTip **for="cmdlnk"**>This is test CMD Link</rich:toolTip>
<a4j:commandLink value="TEst" id="cmdlnka4j"></a4j:commandLink>
<rich:toolTip for="cmdlnka4j">This is test A4j LInk</rich:toolTip>
```

Your New Code :

```
<h:outputLink id="fileDld" rendered="#{docList.docType=='FILE' and not empty docList.docName}" value="/FileDownload" title="Download Documents">
                        <f:param name="fileId" value="#{docList.docId}"/>
                        <f:param name="fileName" value="#{docList.docName}"/>
                        <f:param name="fileSize" value="#{docList.docLength}"/>
                    <h:graphicImage library="images" name="doc_save_icon.png" style="border:0;"/>
                    <rich:tooltip for="fileDld" styleClass="tooltip" layout="block" mode="ajax" value="Download Documents">
                             Download Documents
                    </rich:tooltip>
                </h:outputLink>
```

Comment: hey thanks sugandha its working when i added id & for attribute for it.Thank you so much for your reply