# Richfaces tooltip not working with h:selectOneRadio

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, tooltip

I would like to "bind" a tooltip to a h:selectOneRadio.
Following the example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932962/richfaces-tooltip-not-working-for-houtputlink-tag), I tried with

```
<td>
  <h:selectOneRadio id="subscriptionType" value="#bean.subscriptionType}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{beanModel.subscriptionTypeValues}" />

    <rich:tooltip id="tt1" for="subscriptionType" layout="block" >
      <span style="white-space: nowrap">
             Data is for laptop, modem, ...<br />
             Voice is for smartphone, ...
      </span>
    </rich:tooltip>
  </h:selectOneRadio>
  <h:messages for="subscriptionType" style="color:red; font-size:12px;" />
</td>
```

but the tooltip doesn't appear...

Do I miss something or it is not possible to use tooltips with radio buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I didn't see an error message at the bottom of the page saying

> One or more resources have the target of 'body', but no 'body'
>   component has been defined within the view

So, after having googled for the error message I came to the solution posted [here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/177498?start=0&tstart=0):

*use h:body tag, instead of body*

and now it works!